# Mock mongoose aggregate function in jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I have a middleware as below, for which I am trying to do unit testing using jest,

**Middleware:**

```
import Ph from './Ph.model';
fAP = (req, res, next) => {
        const pN = req.body.pN;
        
        if (pN != null) {

            Ph.aggregate([
                { $match: { 'polNum': { $eq: pN } } },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr:
                        {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ['$pCS', 'A'] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]).exec((err, data) => {

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    req.p = data[0];
                    req.body.pN = data[0].pN;
                    return next();
                } else {
                    return res.json({ message: 'Not found'});
                }

            });
        } else {
            return res.json({ message: 'Cannot be null.'});
        }
    }
```

**Test code:**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

import PhCtrl from 'Ph.controller';
const PhController = new PhCtrl();

import Ph from './Ph.model';

describe('PhController', () => {
  let mockRequest: any;
  let mockResponse: any;
  let mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {
      body: {
        polNum: ''
      }
    };
    mockResponse = {
      json: jest.fn()
    };
  });

  // fAP middleware
  describe('fAP middleware', () => {
    // pN is not null and matches
    describe('when pn is not null', () => {
      // found
      test('should call next when matches', async () => {
        const mockRequest: any = {
          body: {
            pN: '3028'
          }
        };
        const mockResponse: any = {
          json: jest.fn()
        };
        const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();

        const responseData = require('../../../mock-data/p.json');
        
        Ph.aggregate = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
          exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(responseData)
        }));

        await PhController.fAP(
          mockRequest,
          mockResponse,
          mockNext
        );
        expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**Error:**
But I am receiving the following error, when I try to mock aggregate function.
In case of findOne, the similar process works, but fail in aggregation method of mongoose. Any help will be appreciated.

> ● PhController › fAP middleware › when
> pn is not null › should call next when matches
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>
> Expected number of calls: >= 1
> Received number of calls:    0
>
>   54 |           mockNext
>   55 |         );
> > 56 |         expect(mockNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
>      |                          ^
>   57 |       });
>   58 | 
>   59 |       // active ph is not found
>
>   at tests/server/api/ph/ph.controller.test.ts:56:26
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) method to mock `'./Ph.model` module.

Use [mockFn.mockReturnThis()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis) to mock method chain call.

E.g.

`middleware.ts`:

```
import Ph from './Ph.model';

export const fAP = (req, res, next) => {
  const pN = req.body.pN;

  if (pN != null) {
    Ph.aggregate([
      { $match: { polNum: { $eq: pN } } },
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [{ $eq: ['$pCS', 'A'] }],
          },
        },
      },
    ]).exec((err, data) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        req.p = data[0];
        req.body.pN = data[0].pN;
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.json({ message: 'Not found' });
      }
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({ message: 'Cannot be null.' });
  }
};
```

`Ph.model.ts`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema();

const Ph = mongoose.model('Ph', schema);

export default Ph;
```

`middleware.test.ts`:

```
import { NextFunction } from 'express';
import { fAP } from './middleware';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import Ph from './Ph.model';

jest.mock('./Ph.model', () => {
  return {
    aggregate: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    exec: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('66434808', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should call next when matches', () => {
    const responseData = [{ pN: '2222' }];
    mocked(Ph.aggregate().exec).mockImplementationOnce((callback) => {
      callback!(null, responseData);
    });
    const mockRequest: any = { body: { pN: '3028' } };
    const mockResponse: any = { json: jest.fn() };
    const mockNext: NextFunction = jest.fn();
    fAP(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
    expect(Ph.aggregate).toBeCalledWith([
      { $match: { polNum: { $eq: '3028' } } },
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [{ $eq: ['$pCS', 'A'] }],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
    expect(Ph.aggregate().exec).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockNext).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66434808/middleware.test.ts
  66434808
    ✓ should call next when matches (4 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |   81.82 |                   
 middleware.ts |   83.33 |       50 |     100 |   81.82 | 22-26             
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.362 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/66434808

Comment: thank you for the reply, let me try it out.